# What is the best way to upload a directory to Google drive in R

Tags: r, google-api, google-drive-api

The `googledrive` package has the `drive_upload` function to upload a file to Google drive, but how does one go about uploading an entire directory tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @DalmTo 's suggestion, I wrote a method to recursively upload a directory to Google drive:

```r
#' Recursively upload a directory to google drive.
#'
#' @param dir Path to the local directory to upload.
#' @param path Specifies the target destination for the new directory on Google
#'   Drive. Defaults to "My Drive" root folder.
#' @param name New directory name. Defaults to `basename(dir)`.
drive_upload_dir <-
  function(
    dir,
    path = NULL,
    name = NULL) {

    if (is.null(name))
      name <- basename(dir)

    assertthat::assert_that(!is.na(file.info(dir)$isdir), file.info(dir)$isdir, msg = "dir must be a directory")

    sub_path <- googledrive::drive_mkdir(name, path)

    for (p in list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)) {
      if (file.info(p)$isdir) {
        drive_upload_dir(p, path = sub_path)
      } else {
        googledrive::drive_upload(p, path = sub_path)
      }
    }
    return(sub_path)
  }
```

Note that for directory trees with a large number of files it can be very slow. For my uses, it was more expedient to make a tar archive of the directory and `drive_upload` the whole archive.

Answer (score 2):

File upload or [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) with the Google drive api is singular. Each file is created one at a time, in the case of folders those are also created one at a time so.

Loop though your directory tree.  If it's a folder create the folder meta data and store the folder id.   If it's a file then set the parent id to the file id of the folder you created in the previous loop,  and upload the file itself using the create file method.

If you create a recursive method it can be quite elegant.

Comment: Note that for creating the folder there is `googledrive::drive_mkdir` that I used in my answer.